# Access Denied when opening folder in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a simple UWP app that I want to open a folder to access all the files in with. I'm using the stock example code from Microsoft for how to make a folder picker in UWP. However, after picking the folder (any folder) and trying to access it I always get this exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  HResult=0x80070005
  Message=Access to the path 'T:\temp' is denied.
  Source=System.IO.FileSystem
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.FileInfos(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalEnumerateInfos(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()
   at ShutterShock.MainPage.<Button_Click>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\nixca\source\repos\ShutterShock\ShutterShock\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 37
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace ShutterShock
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             string path = await GetOpenLocation();

            var boop = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            boop.EnumerateFiles();

        }

        async Task<string> GetOpenLocation()
        {

            string returnText;

            var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

            if (folder != null)
            {
                // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
                // (including other sub-folder contents)
                Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
                returnText = folder.Path;
            }
            else
            {
                returnText = "Operation cancelled."; //todo make this an exception, catch that exception
            }

            return returnText;
        }

    }
}
```

I get the exception on the "boop.EnumerateFiles();" line.

Answer (score 1):

So of course right after posting this it came to me, but I'll leave this up because I didn't actually find an answer anywhere before asking. The Microsoft example is dumb, and unless all you want is the path of the folder, returning the path is useless. The UWP filepicker doesn't actually grant you System.IO level access to the folder, all it gives you is a StorageFolder you can work on. If you want to do anything useful, you need to return the StorageFolder object, you can use that to actually work on files. This is probably obvious to people who actually know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to get all files in a selected folder, then you can use `folder.GetFilesAsync()`.

```
    var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    if (folder != null)
    {
        var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(file.Path);
        }
    }
```

Here is the my result.
[image]

Comment: Yup, it was just the whole having to use a StorageFolder instead of a DirectoryInfo that threw me. Thanks for the example.